# Load Xdebug per domain? cPanel

Tags: php, cpanel, xdebug

Is it possible to load Xdebug per account? I have access through WHM, but if I load it in `/opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/etc/php.d/php.ini` then every single account becomes very slow

Can I load `xdebug.so` through `.user.ini` or `php.ini` in `public_html`?

Comment: I doubt... but you can try: add section like `[PATH=/path/to/website/root/folder/]` and try loading extension there -- it works with ordinary settings like `sys_temp_dir` or alike. Other than that -- maybe you can specify what PHP config file to use for specific site?

Comment: So I should add `[PATH=/path/to/website/root/folder/]` to the main php.ini file? To `/opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/etc/php.d/php.ini`?

I would try to specify specific PHP config, but I'm not using suPHP, I'm using mod_ruid2 which supports OPcache and is much faster, but it doesn't allow for more than one php.ini per Apache instance

Comment: Yeah -- that is what I had in mind. Not sure if it will work for your case .. as it's a zend_extension loading + Apache...

Comment: I'll try, thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: Didn't work unfortunately, but my idea is possible somehow, I've seen multiple hosting companies do it

Comment: Maybe they have different worker model or different tool is handling PHP part (e.g. php-fpm for example) or something. No better ideas from me.